# What does the principle of implosion imply from a truth-value gap?

Tags: logic, foundations, philosophy, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

The principle of implosion (verum ex quodlibet) states that a valid formula follows from anything. It is expressed:

> B ⊨ A ∨ ¬A

Consider some paracomplete or intuitionistic logic in which the law of excluded middle is rejected, such that there are some statements of the language of the logic which are false and who's negations are also false (or statements which are simply undetermined and without a truth-value).

How does the principle of implosion "react" to such gaps? We know that the principle of *explosion* leads to triviality given a contradiction or *glut*, but would implosion + gaps do the same? Or perhaps this would lead to a complete implosion of the logic, where *no* statements are true?

This may be a simple question for many of you, but I am still fairly new to mathematical logic. The way I am approaching this is by taking the contrapositive,

> ¬(A ∨ ¬A) ⊨ ¬B

which suggests to me that a negated proposition follows from a truth-value gap, but I'm wondering whether ¬B is equivalent to B, given that any B is arbitrary? Or whether this is stating that an arbitrary B *does not hold* given a gap.

I hope I've made myself clear enough, and would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Excluded middle cannot be explicitly rejected in intuitionistic logic in the way your first suggest. $¬A$ ($A$ is false) and $¬¬A$ ($¬A$ is false) contradict each other. So there cannot be a specific $A$ that is false and whose negation is false. Perhaps that answers part of your question: everything follows from $¬(A ∨ ¬A)$ intuitionistically because of explosion. But, it's not clear to me why 'implosion' would be interpreted as $B ⊨ A ∨ ¬A$ there, because $A ∨ ¬A$ is not 'valid.' The trivial validity is often written $⊤$. Intuitionistic logic has $B ⊨ ⊤$ but not (in general) $B ⊨ A ∨ ¬A$.

Comment: Understood, I am wondering what would occur if B⊨A∨¬A was accepted in a logic where A∨¬A is invalid. I'm guessing that the principle of implosion is invalid in intuitionistic logic for a similar reason the principle of explosion is invalid in paraconsistent logic.

Comment: Where are you getting your definition of the "principle of implosion" from?

Comment: I think you mean B => (A => B).

Comment: I first came across it in this: researchgate.net/publication/333755941.
It is also found here as "verum ex quodlibet": link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11229-019-02265-y. This article also labels B => (A => B) as "positive paradox", and I think I have seen this and VEQ equated a few times. I notice that both (A ∧ ¬ A) → B and ¬ A → (A → B) are called "ex falso quodlibet" often. Also, I notice that it is mentioned in another question: math.stackexchange.com/q/3807066/898426

Comment: Probably in this statement, $A \lor \lnot A$ is meant to stand in for the true proposition $\top$ when that symbol is not part of the language under consideration for whatever reason.  For an intuitionistic verison of that, you could probably modify it to something like $B \models A \rightarrow A$.